# python list comprehension not working

Tags: python, list-comprehension, for-comprehension

I have this very simple problem: I need to set the values in list a to 1 for each index in list b:

```
>>> a=[0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> b=[1, 3]
```

the desired result then would be:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1]
```

The elegant solution, if python was worth its salt, would be this of course:

```
>>> a[b]=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

But of course that doesn't work... so I've tried the following list comprehensions, but they both produce the same error, as if the comprehension was causing it (on the for):

First the simple version I was really expecting to work:

```
>>> a[x for x in b] = 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a[x for x in b] = 1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Then the slightly more complex version:

```
>>> a[b[x] for x in range(0,len(b))] = 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a[b[x] for x in range(0,len(b))] = 1
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone see what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: List comprehension creates a list, which can not be used as an index for a list. This is why your attempts fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Using list comprehension

```
In [1]: a=[0, 0, 0, 0]

In [2]: b=[1, 3]

In [3]: [ 1 if i in b else a_i for i, a_i in enumerate(a) ]
Out[3]: [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

#### "The elegant solution, if python was worth its salt, would be this"

Import one module and python is, as you say, worth its salt:

```
In [1]: from numpy import array

In [2]: a = array([0, 0, 0, 0])

In [3]: b = [1, 3]

In [4]: a[b] = 1

In [5]: a
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 0, 1])
```

For handling large quantities of data, `numpy` is both elegant and fast.  If not using `numpy`, then Jonathan Hartnagel's `for` loop or something like Joel Cornett's `BellsAndWhistlesList` would be good solutions.

Comment: list comprehension is less readable than a simple `for`-loop: `for i in b: a[i] = 1`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian My interpretation of the question, yours may differ, was that the OP already understood the simple approach and wanted to know if there was a more "elegant" approach and he specifically asked about list comprehensions.  Therefore, I included one list comprehension solution, even if not elegant, and one elegant solution (numpy).

Comment: even if OP understands it; others might not; I don't see the `for`-loop in the question. OP asks about code where list comprehension is used for indexes. The answer is that *the list comprehension should not be used here*, use the explicit loop instead. Your answer advocates unreadable inefficient (O(n**2)) code.

Comment: I am not "advocating" what you claim.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions and elaborations. You're getting the solution because I was after a one-liner. Even though, as you correctly point out, it is not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with :

```
for i in b:
    a[i] = 1
```

Or, as suggested by @John1024, using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) :

```
from numpy import array
a[b] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try numpy if you want stuff like this:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: a = numpy.zeros(4)

In [3]: b = numpy.array((1, 3))

In [4]: a[b] = 1

In [5]: a
Out[5]: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.])
```

Or plain Python solutions like these:

```
a = [0] * 4
b = [1, 3]
for i in b:
    a[i] = 1
```

Alternatively (slow and inefficient):

```
a = [0] * 4
b = [1, 3]
a = [i in b and 1 or a_i for i, a_i in enumerate(a)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
a = [1 if i in b else v for i,v in enumerate(a) ]
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[x for x in b]
```

Will create:

```
[1, 3]
```

So your code will look like:

```
a[1,3] = 1
```

Which is invalid.

I wouldn't use list comprehension for this, you can simply:

```
for i in b:
    a[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `[1 if i in b else v for i,v in enumerate(a)]` is efficient, since it needs to check whether `i` is in `b` for each `i` in `enumerate(a)`.

As other answers said, `for i in b: a[i] = 1` is the simplest and efficient way, it just set values it needs to directly.

However, if you don't want to use the `for` loop, there is another way to use `map` instead of it to apply operations to all elements of a list. This implement will introduce an function call for each element, so maybe it's not efficient enough either.

```
>>> a=[0,0,0,0]
>>> b=[1,3]
>>> import functools
>>> def set_index(x, l):
...     l[x] = 1
...
>>> mapfunc = functools.partial(set_index, l=a)
>>> map(mapfunc, b)
[None, None]
>>> a
[0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks:

```
class BellsAndWhistlesList(list):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if hasattr(key, "__iter__") or hasattr(key, "next"):
            for i, v in zip(key, value):
                super(BellsAndWhistlesList, self).__setitem__(i, v)
        else:
            super(BellsAndWhistlesList, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
a = [0,0,0,0]
b = [1,3]

for i in range(len(b)):
    a[b[i]] = 1

print a # [0, 1, 0, 1]
```